# Transferring php variables from class to extended class

Tags: php, model-view-controller, class

Basically this is what i want to do:

```
<?php
  class App {
    public $var = "main-class";
    public function load() {
      $this->var =  "child-class";
      $child = new Child;
      $child->echo_var();
    }
  }
  class Child extends App {
    public function echo_var() {
       echo $this->var;
    }
  }

  $app = new Child;
  $app->load();
?>
```

It outputs "main-class", i want it to output "child-class" without having to modify the child class (because i want it to be sort of a "clean" and dynamic class).

I accept suggestions for another course of action

PS: This is part of an Small MVC Framework i'm trying to develop.

Comment: This doesn't seem quite right. To be able to suggest another course of action, you must provide a bit of context. What exactly does `load()` do?

Comment: i have a sort of global var named "models", it's initialised like this:
public $models = array();

and i have a function that populates that array according to classes used in the current controller, 
$this->uses_class("Thumbnail");

which acts on the models, adding to the array... before calling the child class, the array is populated well with the classes that i add, but after, the $models var resets to array()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways that you could do this. Both are going to need to use constructors. With the first one, the child will declare itself when created

```
<?php
class App {
    public $var = "main-class";

    public function __construct($var=null) {
        if($var !== null) {
            $this->var = $var;
        }
    }

    public function load() {
        $child = new Child ();
        $child->echo_var();
    }
}

class Child extends App {
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct("child-class");
    }

    public function echo_var() {
        echo $this->var;
    }
}

$app = new Child();
$app->load();
?>
```

The second one allows the parent to declare the name of the child.

```
<?php
class App {
    public $var = "main-class";

    public function __construct($var=null) {
        if($var !== null) {
            $this->var = $var;
        }
    }

    public function load() {
        $child = new Child ("child-class");
        $child->echo_var();
    }
}

class Child extends App {
    public function echo_var() {
        echo $this->var;
    }
}

$app = new Child();
$app->load();
?>
```

Both of those examples work and do what you want, I believe.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't how inheritance works - By creating a new `Child` object, its data members are all initialized with their default values. When you do `$this->var = ""` in the parent class, you're setting the data members for the `$app` object, not the `$child` object.

You can modify the child class to incorporate a constructor that accepts parameters, and that constructor would set its data members properly. To achieve something similar to what you want, you can use constructors:

```
<?php
  class App {
    public $var = "main-class";
    public function __construct() {
      $this->var =  "child-class";
    }
    public function load() {
      $child = new Child;
      $child->echo_var();
    }
  }
  class Child extends App {
    public function __construct()
    {
      parent::__construct();
    }
    public function echo_var() {
       echo $this->var;
    }
  }

  $app = new App;
  $app->load();
```

Answer (score 0):

I find it very strange that your parent class instanciates it's child. Generally, you would instanciate the child, and you get all the functionality of the parent.

```
$app = new Child();
$app->load();
```

The problem is that you actually have 2 different instanciations. You have an object of App and it's holding a separate object of Child.

The other way to do this would be to make $var a static variable and then it would be available independent of the instantiation. I don't generally recommend making properties static though. It's generally considered bad form (for numerous reasons).

Comment: you are right, sorry!
It was just a typo...

But still, same outcome.